# LinqToSql: How do you read data when you don't know the DB Table yet?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have already been working with linq in the past and I know how to access a database with SqlConnection and SqlCommand. Today I wanted to work with **LinqToSql** and see if and how I can make reading from and writing to a database easier. I did [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/walkthrough-simple-object-model-and-query-csharp) Walkthrough.

Here is the code for the Customer Class (I changed it a bit but it still works perfectly fine):

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
class Customer
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And the code from Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext(@"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=xxx");
        Table<Customer> customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();

        IQueryable query = from cust in customers
                           //where cust.City == "London"
                           select cust;

        foreach (Customer customer in query)
            Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}; City={1}", customer.CustomerID, customer.City);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It worked and I'm happy since this makes accessing a database so much easier for me. But there are still a couple of things that concern me:

1. It seems like for every column I want to include I need to **create a new property** in the Customer class and add a [Column] above it.
2. I need to **create a new Class** for every table that I want to read from (for example Customer, Orders and Suppliers in the Northwind DB).

**First of all this seems to be quite a lot of unnecessary and repetitive work. Am I doing something wrong here?**

Also I want the user to type in the name of a database and a table. This means I don't know yet which database he will pick and I also don't know the structure of the table yet. I can't create the class yet that is supposed to represent the table.

This means I will need to:

1. Create a type / class / object dynamically. I can't use `Table<Customer> customers = db.GetTable<Customer>()` because I don't know the type yet. The type will be the dynamically created class.
2. Mark the type / class / object as a table with `[Table(Name="xxx")]`.
3. Read the columns from the SqlTable and create for every column a property and mark it with [Column].
4. After I'm done with this I can get the table with `Table<T> table = db.GetTable<T>()`, execute the query and display the datarows.

**My second (and more important) question is: How can I do this? Does anyone have code examples or links to share? Or is this approach wrong?**

Comment: Have you ever looked at Dapper? https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper

Comment: What you are trying to do is create your own ORM. Entity Framework does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result in dynamic object just like this.

`dynamic table = db.GetTable<T>()`

and use reflection to get type of the object.